Any reason auto-mode-alist association fails for file extracted from archive-mode file?
My code associates a .crt file to the x509-dwim function with:
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.crt\\'" . x509-dwim))

When I open a .crt X.509 certificate file, the association works fine and the x509-dwim function correctly identifies the X.509 certificate and shows the extracted information as expected.
However, the association fails when I open the file from within the archive-mode buffer rendering of that .zip file: the buffer is opened in Fundamental mode.
Executing (buffer-name) on the buffer returns something like this:
"some.something.net.crt (somefile.something.net_Current.zip)"
Should another entry be placed in the auto-mode-alist to handle buffers that are created from the archive-mode buffer?  Or is something else necessary?
Using Emacs 29.4

Note: I have also tried other regexp in auto-mode-alist with the same results.  I tried (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.crt\\'" . x509-dwim)) for instance.

And I have tried (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.crt\\'" . x509-mode)).  My suspicion at this point is there is something wrong with the x509-mode.el code or my understanding of that code.

I would have expected your last comment to have worked (x509-mode rather than x509-dwim) but the code is doing some funky things that I don't understand yet. You might want to post an issue on the github site.

Hi @NickD, I already posted a question on the Github site.  I also would need to review the entire code.
